# Android Room Database, retrieve specific value of the latest record entered

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-room

I have used Android Room Database to create my app, I am filling records of students, I want to retrieve page number of the latest record that I have entered from the Room Database when I select student's name.
This is my code below
DOA

```
@Dao
public interface NewRecordDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    public void addRecord(NewRecord... newRecord);

    @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
    public void updateRecord(NewRecord newRecord);

    @Delete
    public void deleteRecord(NewRecord newRecord);

    @Query("DELETE FROM newRecord_table")
    void deleteAllRecords();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table ORDER BY NRdate DESC")
    LiveData<List<NewRecord>> getAllRecord();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table WHERE NRdate = (SELECT MAX(NRdate) FROM newRecord_table)")
    LiveData<List<NewRecord>> findRecordByDate ();
}
```

I have a repository class and view model class also but I am not posting those codes here.
Below is the code where I retrieve student's name and mobile number and binding into a spinner. Using this code I want to retrieve page number of the latest record of the student that I select from the spinner.

```
newRecordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(AddRecord.this).get(NewRecordViewModel.class);
        newRecordViewModel.getAllRecords().observe(this, new Observer<List<NewRecord>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<NewRecord> newRecords) {
            }
        });

        selectStudentName.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.select_student_name));
        selectStudentName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, final long l) {
                if ( position == -1 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddRecord.this, "No record is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(AddRecord.this, name + " is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String studentMobile = Objects.requireNonNull(studentViewModel.getAllStudents().getValue()).get(position).getMobileNumber();
                    studentMOB.setText("Mobile: " + studentMobile);
                    recordIds = studentViewModel.getAllStudents().getValue().get(position).getId();

                }
            }
```

I don't know if I am clear enough. I hope I am. Please help.  Thank you

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: @Biscuit I am unable to get that specific data, basically I have an edit text in which I want the page number, that I have already entered while filling data of a particular student. Last page number the student has read.

Comment: @Biscuit I think my last query which mentions findRecordByDate () has some problem with the code. I am not sure how to excute that code.

Comment: You need to create a query with something like `@Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table WHERE newRecord_table.studentid = :studentid ORDER BY newRecord_table.date, newRecord_table.page DESC ")` here `studentId` is variable in your function. You get all the record the student has read

Comment: @Biscuit let me try it out, I hope it works according to my requirement, I am sure solution must be right. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I did  
    ```@Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table WHERE newRecord_table.newRecordId= :recordId ORDER BY newRecord_table.NRdate, newRecord_table.jadeedPage DESC ")
    LiveData<List<NewRecord>> getPage (String recordId);```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new `Query` to fetch what you need.

From what you say you want to find record from one student and display the last page he reads so it should be something like this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table WHERE newRecord_table.studentid = :studentId ORDER BY newRecord_table.date, newRecord_table.page DESC ")
LiveData<List<NewRecord>> findLastPage(Integer studentId);
```

`studentId` is the userId you want to find the records. Don't forget to handle the case where there is nothing.

Comment: this is my record repository  
```public class NewRecordRepository {
    private LiveData<List<NewRecord>> lastPage;

    public NewRecordRepository(Application application) {
        StudentDatabase database = StudentDatabase.getInstance(application);
        lastPageRecord = newRecordDAO.lastPage(0);

    }```

Comment: I am trying to get value like this  
```String page = Objects.requireNonNull(newRecordViewModel.getLastPage().getValue()).get(position).getLastPage();
                    lastPage.setText(page, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);```  
but i am getting null pointer execption

Comment: You're getting a null pointer because of `Objects.requireNonNull`, the result of the query might  be null and it makes your app crash, put a Breakpoint and debug it to see whether or not your `newRecordViewModel.getLastPage().getValue)` is null

Comment: Well i removed the ```Objects.requireNonNull``` 
it give me this error then  
```Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference```   the value is not null, because it is a compulsory value

Comment: I used the debugger as you suggested, it is returning the position but it not returning me the value in that position.