# Room retrieve specific data from latest data entered of specific ID

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

This is actually a follow up question of my last post [Android Room Database, retrieve specific value of the latest record entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834227/android-room-database-retrieve-specific-value-of-the-latest-record-entered)
I used the query suggested by the one who answered my question that was

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table WHERE newRecord_table.studentid = :studentId ORDER BY newRecord_table.date, newRecord_table.page DESC ")
LiveData<List<NewRecord>> findLastPage(Integer studentId);
```

but it does not work in my case, then i used another query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table ORDER BY cast (jadPage as integer) DESC LIMIT 1")
    LiveData<List<NewRecord>> findJadpage();
```

when using the above query with below code

```
selectStudentName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, final long l) {

                    String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    recordIds = studentViewModel.getAllStudents().getValue().get(position).getId();
//                    System.out.println("STUDENT ID: " + recordIds);
//
//                    final int list1 = newRecordViewModel.getAllRecords().getValue().get(position).getId();
//                    System.out.println("LIST ID: " + list1);

                    newRecordViewModel.getJadRecord().observe(AddRecord.this, new Observer<List<NewRecord>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(List<NewRecord> newRecords) {
                            // logic to get jad page..
                            String page = newRecords.get(position).getJadPage();

                            jadPage.setText(newRecords.get(id).getJadPage(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

below is the repository

```
public class NewRecordRepository {
    private NewRecordDAO newRecordDAO;
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;
    private LiveData<List<NewRecord>> jadeedRecord;
    public NewRecordRepository(Application application) {
        StudentDatabase database = StudentDatabase.getInstance(application);
        newRecordDAO = database.newRecordDAO();
        studentDAO = database.studentDAO();
        jadRecord = newRecordDAO.findJadpage();
    }  
    public LiveData<List<NewRecord>> getJadRecord() {
        return jadRecord;
    }
```

but i am getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`
I do not know how to solve this, i have searched the net, found many solutions but it really does not fit in my scenario. Please help.. thank you !

Comment: I am not seeing where you are using the room findJadpage() method in that code, besides if that method is LIMIT 1, the you dont need to make it a LIST<> it will always return just a single Newrecord object

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre i have edited the question and added the method where I cam getting findJadPage() from.

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre tried this method  
```String page = newRecordViewModel.getJadRecord().getValue().get(position).getJadPage();
                    jadPage.setText(page, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);```

Comment: error: ```'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)'```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty simple. you are trying to read positions beyond 0 on a List that only has one entry namely `jadRecord`.
so the solution is just alwys reading the element `0`, like so

```
String page = newRecords.get(0).getJadPage();
```

bacause that list will never have more than one element. there might be other instances where this is an issue

Comment: well I tried the above code, but it give me same page number, no matter which ever student's name I select. every student has a different page number of their latest record entered. the above method returns the value of 0 position of the recycler view. So basically it is back to square one. Thank you for your help though..

Comment: yes that is because you are not filtering by student. the query suggested to you actually seems correct

Comment: I am sorry which query, there are two query mentioned in my question.. Which is the correct one to use to filter.. By student.. I suppose the one which is has student id in it's method..

Comment: the first one seems more correct assuming there is a studentId column in your data you can also add limit 1 to that one if you are only c^gonna use the latest entry

Comment: Okay, you have been a great help. I will try it out and hopefully it works. Will get back to you soon..